# Swift login session rootController UserDefaults error

Tags: swift, authentication, userdefaults

i try to make login session for login, and just any other login session when user is logged in they go straight to Main Menu, and i havent logged in yet but i go straigth to main menu, any help?

here is my code :

```
  func Login() {

     let Email = EmailField.text!
     let Pass = PasswordField.text!

     let api = "http://\(GlobalVariable.ip):7909/api/loginApi? Email=\(Email)&Password=\(Pass)"
    print(api)

    guard let JsonUrl = URL(string: api) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: JsonUrl) { (data, response, error)in
        guard let data = data else { return }

            if let success = try?   JSONDecoder().decode([LoginSuccess].self, from: data).first{

                GlobalVariable.UserId = String(success.id)
                GlobalVariable.UserIdProjectSum =   String(success.id)
                GlobalVariable.UserIdDashboard = String(success.id)
                GlobalVariable.Email = String(success.email)
                GlobalVariable.Name = String(success.name)

                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "IsLog")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() //this is where i put the userDefaults 

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.appDelegate.loginSeque()
                }
            } else if let failure = try?   JSONDecoder().decode([LoginFailed].self, from: data).first {

                //ini buat popup kalo login gagal
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style:   .default, handler: nil)
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login   Fail...", message: "Incorect Email/Password", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:    nil)
                }
           }
        }.resume(). 




      //heres the app delegate



           func application(_ application: UIApplication,   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [.     UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

          LoginSession()
          return true
         }

         func LoginSession() {

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "IsLog") != nil {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main")
        let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        let share = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        share?.window?.rootViewController = navVc
        share?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }else{
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "LogIn", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")
        let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        let share = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        share?.window?.rootViewController = navVc
        share?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

          }


   func loginSeque() {


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let navbar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navBar")
    window?.rootViewController = navbar

     }
```

so the error is i keep getting to main menu even i havent log in yet, maybe i did something wrong in my code or i make mistakes in my algorithm? thanks for the help:)

Comment: where do you skip UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "IsLog")? if it exists in memory you will be always "logged in"

Comment: i read from the tutorial that he only put that line for userDefault, so if that is wrong what should i do?

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "IsLog") on logout or on failure

Comment: delete the app and install again and observe whether this is happening in the first launch also

Comment: i delete the apps and it works its load from the login screen, but when i logged in i quit the apps and reopen it, but the data that login wasnt store